# Reflection get fundamental types

Tags: c#, reflection, primitive, primitive-types

Looking for a way to get the fundamental/core types in c# **without** using the IsPrimitive and a bunch of "||". Basically I want the decimal, datetime, string to be included, but I don't want to specifically look for them.

I remember seeing something to the effect of checking the fundamental type of the object, and see if it inherits from object.

Can someone point me in the right direction how to do this?

Also how would this method categorize the primitive nullables?

Comment: What's a "fundamental" type for you? The set of types that are considered "primitives" in .NET is finite; just set up a `HashSet<Type>` and check for  containedness? There is no `IsFundamental` property.

Comment: "Primitive nullables" are instances of the generic `Nullable<T>` struct, where T is a primitive type. (Or a boxing type corresponding to a primitive type, not sure.)

Comment: Could you explain why do you want to know this?

Comment: In .NET, primitive types aren't _that_ primitive compared to other types, they're just structs that behave a bit different in some cases. `DateTime` is just a struct like any other. So why not make a list or `Dictionary` of what you consider to be primitives?

Comment: Technically, according to the C# specs, there are no such things as "primitives", no definition of the term, nor any list of types, exists there.  If you want to create your own definition that's fine, but just recognize that it is your own definition and develop your solution accordingly.

Comment: The DateTime, the string, nullable of a primitive off the top of my head. Hoping there's a well accepted convention for this this already and a way to determine them w/o a custom made hash table or set of conditional statements.

Comment: Also, why do you not want to use `IsPrimitive`? It makes a hell of a lot of sense to me.

Comment: @Alwyn Please define fundamental. `DateTime` is a struct without anything special about it, and `string` is a reference type. They don't have much in common. There is `IsPrimitive`, but I've never come across a situation where this was a useful distinction. So why do you want to know what's "fundamental"?

Comment: @Alwyn How are `string`s primitive then? They certainly don't return `true` for `IsPrimitive`. (`int` seem to though.) It really seems like your choice of classes is arbitrary as far as the framework when it comes to metadata available via reflection is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get a list of all fundamental data types (which aren't that fundamental to start with, they just behave a bit differently compared to other structs), you will have to use `IsPrimitive`. I could understand not wanting to use `||`, but `IsPrimitive` makes a lot of sense to me.

Also, `DateTime` has no good reasons to be considered fundamental/primitive. `DateTime` is just your regular struct.

Here is the best method I could come up with:

```
List<Type> types = typeof(string).Assembly.GetTypes()
                   .Where(t => t.IsPrimitive).ToList();
types.Add(typeof(string));
types.Add(typeof(decimal));
```

That will search mscorlib (`typeof(string).Assembly`) for any types, and only selects the primitives (`System.DateTime` is not in the list, but you can add it if you want). The `string` and `decimal` types are included because they *could* be considered to be fundamental types.

Comment: `string` is special. It doesn't behave like any other class. For example you can have string constants, it's one of very few (array and string come to mind) variable size types.

Comment: So, you consider `IntPtr`, which is treated in a special way by .Net, but not by C#, “fundamental”. And you also consider `decimal`, which is treated in a special way by C#, but not .Net. Does that mean that according to you, the set of “fundamental” types is the union between “types with keywords in C#” and “primitive types in .Net”?

Comment: @svick This is why I had difficulty answering the question in the first place. There is simply no good definition when it comes to fundamental data types in C# _or_ .NET. There will therefore always be a subjective factor.